Issue with get ranges using getRangeList
I am trying to get ranges by using getRangeList method but I am getting error Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList
How can we do it?
function consolidateData() {
  // defined all variables
  var sheetNames = [];
  var dataSheet = [];
  var conso = [];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var applyTo = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet10');
  // get all sheets
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    sheetNames[s] = sheet.getName();
    dataSheet[s] = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[s]);
    // adding all sheet's data to a single variable
    conso = conso.concat(dataSheet[s].getRange("A2:B" + dataSheet[s].getLastRow()).getValues());
    // conso = conso.concat(dataSheet[s].getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"] + dataSheet[s].getLastRow()).getValues());

  }
  applyTo.getRange("A2:B" + (conso.length + 1)).setValues(conso);
  // applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"] + (conso.length + 1)).setValues(conso);
}


Modification according to the Wicket guidelines is unresolved below.

function consolidateData() {
  // defined all variables
  var sheetNames = [];
  var dataSheet = [];
  var conso = []; 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var applyTo = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet10');
  // get all sheets
  var allsheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var s in allsheets) {
    var sheet = allsheets[s];
    sheetNames[s] = sheet.getName();
    dataSheet[s] = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[s]);
    // adding all sheet's data to a single variable
    conso = conso.concat(dataSheet[s].getRange("A2:B" + dataSheet[s].getLastRow()).getValues());
    // conso = conso.concat(dataSheet[s].getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"] + dataSheet[s].getLastRow()).getValues());

  }
  // applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"] + (conso.length + 1)).setValues(conso);
  applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"].map( e =>  e + (conso.length + 1))  // According to Wicket guidelines
}


Stack Snippets should be used only for runnable code in Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, the Google Apps Script code is not runnable because Stack Overflow Stack Snippets doesn't support Google Apps Script services like Class SpreadsheetApp. The code in my answer put in Stack Snippets don't make calls to SpreadsheetApp methods

I just added an example for your understanding only.

If the example is a follow-up question / derived from an answer then it should be posted in a new question, not as an edit.

You might want to manually wrap the comments, as some parts are hidden / require scrolling to the right. Including a brief description on top of the inserted parts is also a good practice.

The question was "Issue with get ranges using getRangeList", Your expression is return range, but it does not work with my example script.

That is the question title. The specific problem is an error. Anyway, you are not obliged to accept my answer or follow my suggestions. Be patient; maybe someone will come and post the answer you are looking for.

The error

Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList

is caused by the expression ["A2:B","D2:E"] + (conso.length + 1) because it doesn't return an array of valid range references in A1 notation format.


const conso = [[1,2],[3,4]];
const a1Notations = ["A2:B","D2:E"] + (conso.length + 1);
/* Log output : 
A2:B,D2:E3

Please note that the above is a string, not an Array of strings
*/
console.log(a1Notations);



Error Fix
Below is the fix for the specific error
From
applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"] + (conso.length + 1))

to
applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"].map( e =>  e + (conso.length + 1))



const conso = [[1,2],[3,4]];
const a1Notations = ["A2:B","D2:E"].map(e => e + (conso.length + 1));
/* Log output : 
[
  "A2:B3",
  "D2:E3"
]
*/
console.log(a1Notations);



Note: This answer is not intended to fix the whole code. Please check out getValues From getRangeList.

I am sorry, I could not understand the reference with your answer. Can you please answer with my script and your snippet as an example?

@Smaller It's not too complicated: Replace the code indicated in the From section with the code in the To section and toggle the comments. If you still need help, post a follow-up question including a [mcve].

You meant I just needed to replace it with applyTo.getRangeList(["A2:B","D2:E"].map( e =>  e + (conso.length + 1)) But how do I apply with setValue?

That is a follow-up question. Follow-up questions should be posted as a new question.

What is applyTo? I can't find that in my Javascript Reference.

@Cooper applyTo is a variable declared in OP code : var applyTo = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet10');

@ Wicket, your suggestion appears with this error: TypeError: applyTo.getRangeList(...).setValues is not a function.

@Smaller That is because setValues is not a method of SpreadsheetApp.getRangeList. See getValues From getRangeList If you need further help, please consider to post a new question.
